# Simplify $w^{3n}, w^{6n}, w^{3 + 3n}, w^{4+3n}$, etc. using $w^3=1$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I having an expression containing terms that are powers of $w$. How can I simplify these terms using the assumption $w^3=1$?

```
Simplify[expr, w^3==1 && n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

doesn't work for terms that have symbolic variable, e.g. $n$, in the exponent.

EDIT:
Example expression:

```
( -a*w^3 + b*(n+1)*w^6 + 9*w^(3+3*n)*Sum[d[i], {i,1,n}]^2 - w^(3+6*n)*Sum[c[i], {i,1,n}] ) / (s^2*w^(4 + 3*n) )
```

Comment: Kindly provide us `expr` so we have an example to work with

Comment: @JackLaVigne I added an example for the expression.

Comment: You only have to give a rule w^n_- >If[n==3 ,1,w^(n-3)]` (sorry actually No MMA acces)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $w^3=1$, one can use $w^\alpha=w^{\alpha \text{ mod } 3}$ to simplify arbitrary powers of $w$. This can be implemented as a simple rule:

```
wrule = w^(x_) :> w^Refine[Mod[x, 3], Assumptions->Element[n, Integers]];
```

Examples:

```
{w^1, w^2, w^3, w^4, w^(3n), w^(6n), w^(3+3n), w^(4+3 n), w^(-4-3n)} /. wrule
```

> {w, w^2, 1, w, 1, 1, 1, w, w^2}

Comment: Nice solution but I believe you need to treat negative integers differently. Applying `w^-4/.wrule` results in `w^2`. I think it should result in `1/w` (i.e., `w^-1`).

Comment: @JackLaVigne If `w^3==1` then `w^-1 == 1 * w^-1 == w^3 * w^-1 == w^2`. Thus both results are actually the same.

Comment: You are so right, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

A good strategy when attempting to replace portions of an expression is to look at the `FullForm`.

Below is an example expression:

```
expr = w^4 + w^(3 n) + w^(6 n) + w^(3 + 3 n) + w^(4 + 3 n)
```

and the associated `FullForm`

```
FullForm[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By examining the `FullForm` of `expr` we see three forms where `w` is raised to a power involving integers: directly, with a times or with a plus and times.

Use patterns with `ReplaceAll` to accomplish the job.

```
expr //. {
  Power[w, Plus[integer_Integer /; integer > 2, rest_]] -> 
   Power[w, Plus[integer - 3, rest]],
  Power[w, integer_Integer] -> Power[w, integer - 3],
  Power[w, Times[integer_Integer, n]] -> 
   Power[w, Times[integer - 3, n]]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

Upon request, the following expression was given as an example.

```
expr = (-a*w^3 + b*(n + 1)*w^6 + 
    9*w^(3 + 3*n)*Sum[d[i], {i, 1, n}]^2 - 
    w^(3 + 6*n)*Sum[c[i], {i, 1, n}])/(s^2*w^(4 + 3*n))
```

Now one additional rule to handle negative integers is required.

```
expr //. {
  Power[w, Plus[integer_Integer /; integer > 2, rest_]] -> 
   Power[w, Plus[integer - 3, rest]],
  Power[w, Plus[integer_Integer /; integer < -2, rest_]] -> 
   Power[w, Plus[integer + 3, rest]],
  Power[w, integer_Integer] -> Power[w, integer - 3],
  Power[w, Times[integer_Integer, n]] -> 
   Power[w, Times[integer - 3, n]]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One might want to go further and assume that `n` is an integer. I leave that as an exercise for you.